# How do I apply (or edit) a broad set of styles to only one class/ID?

Tags: html, css

I know the basics of css and have never had any trouble with this before... however I'm currently playing around with an example of a css drop down list using the following css:

```
<style type="text/css">
  ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  ul li a:hover {background: #f00;}
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: #f00;}
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
</style>
```

and the following example html:

```
<ul id="drop-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Content Management</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Concrete 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It works fine but obviously the css also affects any other lists on the page. I want all of the css to apply to only child elements of #drop-nav.

I am unsure as to the best way to achieve this? I've tried prefixing/postfixing the css rules with the ID but while it works for some of the rules it seems to break other ones and I can't see why.

Ideally I'd like an answer which teaches me how to understand this problem better.... I don't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dont select your elements based on `ul` becouse this will affect all of your `ul` elements. Select them based on the id `#drop-nav` which is unique.

Try:

```
<style>
  #drop-nav {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  #drop-nav li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
  #drop-nav li ul {display: none;}
  #drop-nav li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;               white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  #drop-nav li a:hover {background: #f00;}
  #drop-nav li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  #drop-nav li:hover li {float: none;}
  #drop-nav li:hover a {background: #f00;}
  #drop-nav li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
</style>
```

Comment: I had to change the first rule to: ul#drop-nav, ul#drop-nav li ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        } 

but otherwise your answer worked perfectly thanks! I was really looking for the underlying logic in how you had done this though. Basically it appears I append the ID to the rule unless the rule was applying to the element itself in which case I need to select the ID rather than the element.... and then sort out any rules where I'm expecting it to be applied to both the element and any sub elements of the same type.

Answer (score 4):

Please try to add `#drop-nav` before all `li` rules and change first `ul` to `#drop-nav` like:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #drop-nav {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  #drop-nav li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
  #drop-nav li ul {display: none;}
  #drop-nav li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  #drop-nav li a:hover {background: #f00;}
  #drop-nav li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  #drop-nav li:hover li {float: none;}
  #drop-nav li:hover a {background: #f00;}
  #drop-nav li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
</style>
```